# Searching a List of Objects for those Objects with a Particular Member Variable set to a Value?

Tags: python

```
import string
import random

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

foos = []
for i in range(1,101):
    f = foo(random.choice(string.letters))
    foos.append(f)

fs == find_object_in_list_by_attribute(bar='b')
```

Is there a method like `find_object_in_list_by_attribute` in python to accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly do you want your `find_in_object` return?

Comment: @RubenBermudez I would like it to return the objects in the list whose `bar` member variable equals `b`, in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `[, if <filter>]` grammar of list comprehensions to give you the foos with `bar == 'b'`:

```
fs = [foo for foo in foos if foo.bar == 'b']
```

sidenotes: classes should start with capital letters (like ruby, but just *strongly recommended* instead of compulsory) and range objects are written as `for i in range(100):`.

In the event that you just want the *first* foo (which may or may not be the only foo), you can do:

```
fs = next(foo for foo in foos if foo.bar == 'b')
```

This will notably raise a `StopIteration` exception if `'b'` is not found anywhere in your `foos` collection, so you can give `next` a "fallback" value to avoid that:

```
fs = next((foo for foo in foos if foo.bar == 'b'), None)
```

Comment: Great; thanks. Question edited. Would you know of a way to do this (aside from appending [0]) and return one object instead of a list (in the event that your list had unique values for the particular member variable?)

Comment: Yup, see edit.  `next` with a gen expression is more efficient than taking the first element from a list comp, because it is lazily evaluated (i.e. doesn't need to keep evaluating after returning the first foo where `bar == 'b'`).

Comment: Awesome; much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it overriding your `==` operator for your class (in python, method `__eq__`). Something like:

```
import string
import random

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __eq__(self, letter):
        return self.bar == letter

foos = []
for i in range(1,101):
    f = foo(random.choice(string.letters))
    foos.append(f)

foos.append(foo("z")) # I'm appending this one to be sure that there is a foo with letter z in the list, this is just for testing purpose

print foos[foos.index("z")].bar
```

Just be sure you don't need to compare to `foo` object, just `foo` with a letter. If you do, you should make some checks in `__eq__` method.